# git is not able to create .git-credentials

Tags: git, clion, mingw-w64, msys2

I've run into some bizarre troubles with git, CLion and GitHub Desktop.
I've installed msys64, configured my path to use `C:\msys64\bin` folder. Every command in git works fine, my git version is 2.26, except the `git push` one. Once I enter the command for any local repository, the output is:

```
fatal: cannot run git credential-store get: No such file or directory
fatal: cannot run git credential---help get: No such file or directory
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

And it asks me for my login and password. This happens every time despite that I've configured gitconfig to store the credentials. I tried to delete all gitconfig files present, reinstalling git package from msys2 and doing everything again, but with no luck.
This is my git `config --list output`

```
core.autocrlf=true
credential.helper=store
credential.helper=store
```

I don't encounter any issues when pushing using desktop client, it all started with CLion: It was infinitely stuck when I tried to push changes, everything else worked. Here is a snippet of a CLion idea.log file:

```
INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - error: cannot run C:\Users\ender\.CLion2019.3\system\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.bat: No such file or directory
```

However the file is present and accessible. I'd enter my username or password every time or save them in my gitconfig, no problem, but CLion depends on the `git config --global credential.helper store` parameter to be set and there is no way to configure it to behave otherwise AFAIK.

Comment: The various `git-credential-*` files (there are four on my not-Windows-at-all system) should have been installed in the `git-core` directory (as shown by `git --exec-path`) when you installed Git itself. That suggests a bad Git package, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer. The executable exists, I was wrong, but the issue persists

Comment: OK. I have no idea what's going wrong at this point; I avoid Windows...